# Wordpress Date Display Conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm building an events directory on Wordpress, and have a listing of events on my homepage, categories and search results pages. Sample image of page: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKp4r.jpg)

As you can see the listing displays both Start and End dates. It does this for all events, even if the start and end dates are the same. I would like to create the following conditions:

- If Start Date & End Date are equal, then display only the start date.

else

- If Start Date & End Date are not equal, then display both. **OR** If End Date is greater thans Start Date, display both.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<span class="date">

<?php if($post->post_type == 'post'){
echo $date = date_i18n("d M",strtotime($post->post_date)); 
}else{
echo $date = date_i18n("d M",strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'st_date',true))).' to       
'.date_i18n("d M",strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'end_date',true))); 
}
?>
</span>
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Why are you checking for post type . Does it have anything to do with events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<span class="date">
    <?php 

    if($post->post_type == 'post'){
        $date = date_i18n("d M",strtotime($post->post_date));
    } else {
        if (strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'st_date',true)) == strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'end_date',true))) {
            $date = date_i18n("d M",strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'st_date',true)));
        } else {
            $date = date_i18n("d M",strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'st_date',true))) . ' to ' .date_i18n("d M",strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'end_date',true)));
        }
    }

    echo $date;
    ?>
</span>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: @user2286485 Cool let me know if you need any more help.